# How to set compiler in embarcadero C++ builder?

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder

How to set compiler in embarcadero C++ builder? I want to set bcc64 as a compiler, but cannot see the option for it, and my projects are being compiled with bcc32.

Comment: Why not use a more conventional toolchain, such as GCC or Visual Studio? Join the 21st century?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have to say that I disagree with you. Clang is much better than gcc and bcc64 which is used by embarcadero is based on this compiler. As for Visual Studio? Meh, not as long as their C++11 support will be in 1990's. And performance. And look ;). Simply cannot stand it (VS2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE chooses the compiler for you, based on what type of file is being compiled and what Platform it is being compiled for.  If you want to compile a 64-bit executable, you have to go into the Project Manager and add a 64-bit Platform to the project first and then set it as the active Platform.  A project can have multiple Platforms added, each with its own set of configuration options.  This is covered in detail on [Embarcadero's online wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/64-bit_Cross-Platform_Application_Development_for_Windows).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did it and indeed now it compiles and links correctly. Unfortunately I cannot run my exe file - the error I'm getting is that the ver of Windows I'm running is incompatible. I'm running Win7 x86, does that mean that I need to have Win x64 in order to run application which has been compiled in x64 mode?

Comment: @user336359: Of course.. how can you run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit computer..... you do not have sufficient bits....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, that's what I've thought. Silly me. +1